# Atlassian Jira - What's called first on Jira state transition - Webhook or post function?

Tags: jira, webhooks

I'm very new to Jira, and still on exploring phase. I've an application that makes use of web hooks as well as post functions applied both on state change (transition).

Now as I understand, both gets called on State change, hence my question - Is there a priority if web hooks will be called first or post functions after state is changed ?

Answer (score 0):

The execution of webhooks is a postfunction itself. At least indirectly.

Webhooks are based on certain issue events, like 'updated', 'created' etc. When looking at the default postfunctions of a transition, there is an entry at the end which fires an event for this transition. On a 'create' transition, this will be a 'issue created event' but on most others it will be a 'generic event'. If this event matches the webhook settings, it will be triggered at that point.

[image]

It is also possible to create custom events for more specific execution than what the built-in events allow for. You can also control the order of the postfunctions and fire the event before some other action you want executed afterwards.

This is documentation on such a custom event implementation. The same principle applies to the default events included in Jira:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-use-a-webhook-with-a-custom-event-779160676.html